# Elasticsearch date parsing issue with default format

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My es version is 7.5.1

And the mapping is:

```
"dynamic": "strict",
    "properties"{
     ...
    "memberDOB": {
    "type": "date"
    }
    ...
 }
```

As per this link, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html it says:

Date formats can be customised, but if no format is specified then it uses the default:
`"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"`

while writing data to es with memberDOB value in epoch as -3715200000 which is '1969-11-19', I got this issue:
MapperParsingException[failed to parse field [memberDOB] of type [date] in document with id 'ACX03:xcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxcxc'. Preview of field's value: '-3715200000']; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[date_time_exception: **Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -3715200000]**

From the mentioned exception, it seems that the epoch date is being treated as yyyy-mm-dd format.

I also updated the format as `"format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"` in new index and tried to write, but still same error occurs.

But when I update the format as `"format":"epoch_millis"`, it works.

Could someone explain why this is happening or what am I missing here (for default format)?